# Using doubles to Wage/Bet ( HiLo Dice-roll Game)

Tags: java, validation, while-loop, double

I have a working 10-sided dice roll HiLo guessing game, correct as:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        //roll one
        int rNum1 = (int)(10*Math.random()+1); //declare random roll one,  gives result between 1 and 10

        //print roll one
        System.out.println("You roll the 10-sided die."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum1 + "."); //result between 1 and 10
        System.out.println(); //space

        //User guess
        System.out.println("Will a second die roll higher or lower?");
        System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");

        //roll two
        int rNum2 = (int)(10*Math.random()+1); //declare random roll two, gives result between 1 and 10
        int guess = input.nextInt(); //user's guess / HiLo

        //invalid user entry
        while(guess != 1 && guess != 2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry"); // print incorrect guess entry input
            System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");
            guess = input.nextInt(); //reset scanner "input"
        }

        //print roll two
        System.out.println(); //space
        System.out.println("You roll the die again."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum2 + "."); //result between 1 and 10
        System.out.println(); //space

        if (guess == 1) //guessed higher
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            }
        }

        if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
            }
        }
```

Now I am attempting to allow the user to bet. Allowing the user to set an initial value (double initial) and wage (double wager) from their pot (double money) based on correct HiLo guesses. If they lose, they lose their wager, if they win they get 150% of wager:

```
if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2) //draw
            {
                System.out.println("Draw! Nothing lost, nothing gained!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2) //correct guess
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                money = money*1.5; //150% gain
                run++; //adds 1 to run
            }
            else //incorrect guess
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
                money = money - wager; //wager lost
            }
        }

        //total
        total = (initial + wager) - money;

total = (initial + wager) - money;
```

I have also enclosed the program in a while-loop (where boolean cashOut is false) so that users can choose to finishing the game by cash out after each roll (change cashOut to true) or if pot reaches zero.

```
while(money != 0 && (cashOut = false)) {
}
```

I set up printlns outside the while which after cashing out or game over, returns the number of correct guesses and the total amount of money bet and cashed out.

```
System.out.println("Game over! Thanks for playing!");
System.out.println("Correct guesses = " + run + ".");
System.out.println("Total bet = " + total + ".");
System.out.println("Cashed out = " + money + ".");
```

However now when asking user for the initial (between 10 and 100) the system returns nothing, whether the validation conditions are met or not. I have attempted to debug program for 6 hours to no avail. Can anybody spot my mistake?

===================

Full code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int run = 0; //correct guesses

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //user's stakes
    System.out.println("How much cash are you betting with today? (Enter int 10 & 100)");
    double initial = input.nextDouble();

    //invalid user stake entry
    while(!(initial < 10 && initial > 100)); 
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry"); // print incorrect guess entry input
        System.out.println("Enter between 10 & 100.");
        initial = input.nextInt(); //reset scanner "input"
    }

    boolean cashOut = false;
    double money = initial;
    double total = initial;  

    while(money != 0 && (cashOut = false))
    {
        System.out.println("What is your wager? (to 1 d.p.)");
        double wager = input.nextDouble();

        //roll one
        int rNum1 = (int)(10*Math.random()+1); //declare random roll one,  gives result between 1 and 10

        //print roll one
        System.out.println("You roll the 10-sided die."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum1 + "."); //result between 1 and 10
        System.out.println(); //space

        //User guess
        System.out.println("Will a second die roll higher or lower?");
        System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");

        //roll two
        int rNum2 = (int)(10*Math.random()+1); //declare random roll two, gives result between 1 and 10
        int guess = input.nextInt(); //user's guess / HiLo

        //invalid user entry
        while(guess != 1 && guess != 2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry"); // print incorrect guess entry input
            System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");
            guess = input.nextInt(); //reset scanner "input"
        }

        //print roll two
        System.out.println(); //space
        System.out.println("You roll the die again."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum2 + "."); //result between 1 and 10
        System.out.println(); //space

        if (guess == 1) //guessed higher
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw! Nothing lost, nothing gained!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
                money = money - wager; //wager lost
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                money = money*1.5; //150% gain
                run++; //adds 1 to run
            }
        }

        if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw! Nothing lost, nothing gained!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                money = money*1.5; //150% gain
                run++; //adds 1 to run
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
                money = money - wager; //wager lost
            }
        }

        //total
        total = (initial + wager) - money;

        //cashout
        System.out.println("To cash out enter [cp]");
        String cashoutChoice = input.next().toLowerCase();
        if (cashoutChoice.equals("cp"))
        {
            cashOut = true;
        }

        System.out.println(); //space
    }

    System.out.println("Game over! Thanks for playing!");
    System.out.println("Correct guesses = " + run + ".");
    System.out.println("Total bet = " + total + ".");
    System.out.println("Cashed out = " + money + ".");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your first **while** loop you have placed a semicolon (;) at the end of your condition for the loop. Remove it since this is just forcing things to think this is an **Empty Statement** after the **while** which then forces the EDT to indefinitely cycle on this line until the application is manually forced to shut down.

Your condition is also in error. Since you only want values including and between 10 and 100 what you really want to have for a condition is:

```
while (initial < 10 || initial > 100) { ... }
```

A slightly better way to do the entire loop might be:

```
//user's stakes
double initial = 0.0;

//invalid user stake entry
while (initial < 10 || initial > 100) {
    System.out.println("How much cash are you betting with today?\n"
                     + "Enter a value between 10 & 100: ");
    initial = input.nextDouble();
    if (initial < 10 || initial > 100) {
        // Print incorrect input entry
        System.err.println("Invalid entry!\n");
        input.nextLine(); // ** Clear Scanner Buffer.
    }
}
```

This however does not take care of business if alpha characters are supplied other than the decimal point which will ultimately throw a **InputMismatchException**. Lot's of code examples in *StackOverflow* which show you how to take care of this as well. Search for them.

But, this is only part of your problem. After the **Initial** Stake value has been supplied your code will now go directly to ***Game End*** because of the condition supplied within the next **while** loop within your code, the **Wager Prompt Loop**:

```
boolean cashOut = false;
double money = initial;
double total = initial;

while (money != 0 && (cashOut = false)) { .... }
```

Above the **while** loop you declare and initialize the the boolean **cashOut** variable to **false** which is fine but in your **while** loop condition you continually force **cashout** to equal **false** because you're using a single equals (**=**) character within the condition. `=` is not the same as `==` which is what should be used within your condition:

```
while (money != 0 && cashOut == false) { .... }
```

Using a single equals sign within a condition simply makes the **cashOut** variable equal whatever boolean is placed after it which in your case, is **false**. Use `==` in conditional statements.

This should now get you going. Also consider not allowing the User to supply a wager greater that what remains in their stake balance.